# Exponential integral identity

Tags: integration

Found this today when playing around with desmos

$$Ei\left(-1\right)+\frac{1}{e}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{x}x^{2}}dx$$

Proof?

Ei(x) is the exponential integral.

Answer (score 3):

For a proof of your identities: Note that $$\int_0^1 \exp(-1/x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_1^\infty x^{-2} \exp(-x)\,\mathrm dx$$ follows from the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$.

Now, integrating by parts gives $$\int_1^\infty x^{-2}\exp(-x)\,\mathrm dx = \color{green}{\left[- x^{-1}\exp(-x)\right]^\infty_1}+\color{blue}{(-1)^3}\color{orange}{\int_1^\infty x^{-1}\exp(-x)\,\mathrm dx}=\color{green}{\frac1e}\color{blue}-(\color{orange}{-\operatorname{Ei}(-1)})=\frac1e+\operatorname{Ei}(-1).$$